# how to capture console.log from node.js to my php web page?

Tags: php, node.js, output

i'm trying to get my console.log() output from my node.js, appear on my php web page. 
is there any chance that i could do this? 
i tried to googled everywhere, seems there are no clear answer to this question.

your help will be very useful. Thanks so much.

Comment: You could spool the output of node to a file and read that from PHP. Fx. `node entry.js > /tmp/foobar`, and from PHP do a  `file_get_contents("/tmp/foobar")`. If you have a huge amount of output, consider using a stream in PHP instead, i.e. `fopen`.

Comment: What output? The output it makes to the console if you just run it? The output it makes in an HTTP response if you make an HTTP request to it? The output it logs to the console when stuff happens as it continuously runs as a server?

Comment: thanks for your response, the output that it makes to the console if i run the node.js.. i want to show it on my php. can i?

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
And [How to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: And **WHO** upvotes a badly written question like this. **Stop It**

Answer (score -1):

You can use [logs](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2) to capture the **console.log** from node.js, Run the following console command.

```
pm2 logs                      # Display logs of all apps
pm2 logs [app-name]           # Display logs for a specific app
```

https://github.com/Unitech/pm2

> Make sure you're using console.log() for log purpose only and to output anything at client side.

Comment: thanks for the answer. If i may ask, how can  i connect my node.js and my php? is there any specific sytanx to connect them?

Comment: What do you mean by connecting PHP and node.js? Do you want to get the output from node.js to PHP file?